# Matplotlib segmented Plot

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, plot

I have the following dataset:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame ({"a": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 
                'b':[1,2,3,4,50,60,70,8,9,10,110,120,130,140,150,16,17,18,19,20],
                'c':[np.nan,2.2,3.4,np.nan,40.9,60.2,np.nan,8.2,8.9,10.1,np.nan,120.2,
                     130.07,140.23,np.nan,16.054,17.20,18.1,np.nan,20.1],
               'd': [100, np.nan,np.nan, 500,np.nan, np.nan,500, 
                     np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,100, np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,500,
                     np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,100,np.nan  ]}
              )
```

I am trying to plot the data based on the following conditions:

1. Between 100 to the next 100 in column 'd' I want to have one
   plot having column 'a' in the x axis, and scatterplot of column  'b' and line plot of 'c' in the y axis.
   That is I will be having 3 different plots. First one from index 0 to 10, second one from index 10 to index 18, third one from 18 to 20. (I can generate this using for loop)
2. Within each plot I want segmented lineplot based on the location 500 value in column 'd',i.e., for the first plot from index 0-3 one lineplot, from index 3-6 another and from index 6-10 another lineplot.( I can't make the segmented lineplot)

I am using the following codes:

```
    index = index + [len(df)]
    index1 = index1 + [len(df)]

   for k in range (len(index)-1):
      x = df['a'][index[k] + 1:index[k+1]]
      y = df['c'][index[k]+ 1:index[k+1]]
      y1 = df['b'][index[k]+ 1:index[k+1]]

      plt.scatter(x, y)
      plt.plot(x, y1)
      plt.savefig('plot'+ str(k+1000) +'.png')
      plt.clf()
```

My first plot look like this: (But want to have three segmented
lineplot not the continuous one   (that is line from index 0-3 should not be connected with 3-6 and so on) [image]

Sorry for the rather long question and thx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output is unclear, but here is a general strategy to split your dataset in groups with help of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

##### option 1: independent figures

```
group = df['d'].eq(100).cumsum()
for name, g in df.groupby(group):
    f,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(g['a'], g['c'])
    ax.plot(g['a'], g['b'])
    f.savefig(f'figure_{name}.png')
```

##### option 2

```
ax = plt.subplot()
group = df['d'].eq(100).cumsum()
for name, g in df.groupby(group):
    ax.scatter(g['a'], g['c'])
    ax.plot(g['a'], g['b'], label=name)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

##### option 3

```
ax = plt.subplot()
group = df['d'].eq(100).cumsum()
for name, g in df.groupby(group):
    g = g.reset_index()
    ax.scatter(g.index+1, g['c'])
    ax.plot(g.index+1, g['b'])
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to plot three different figures, i.e. your blue line in one figure, orange in another and green in another. But within the blue line I want three different segment from index 0-3, 3-6, 6-10. So, the blue line won't be one continuous line rather should be segmented to three different lines. Same is true for the other two plots as well.

Comment: Then do the exact same thing but create and save the figure inside the loop

Comment: @Aimas see update

Comment: for name, g in df.groupby(group):
    index = [k for k, value in enumerate (g['d']) if (value==500) | (value==100)]
    index = index + [len(g)]
    print (index)
    for i in range(len(index)-1):
        x = g['a'][index[i] + 1:index[i+1]]
        y = g['c'][index[i]+ 1:index[i+1]]
        y1 = g['b'][index[i]+ 1:index[i+1]]
    
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.plot(x, y1)
        
    plt.savefig('plot'+ str(name+200) +'.png')
    plt.clf()